# How to see what riches are hidden inside the Microsoft Word template (*.dot or *.dotx) file?

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, templates

I have an old `report.dot` file. My client sent me `new_report.docx` file and said that this `new_report.docx` file shows how the new template `new_report.dot` should look now and how I should modify my old `report.dot` template into new `new_report.dot` template. This is essentially about Word tables.

I don't know what to do? I can simply save `new_report.docx` as `new_report.dot` and say that my job has been done. But I am afraid that the old report.dot can contain some bookmarks (placeholds), some active spots, elements - I have no idea - what else? I.e. report.doc can contain some hidden riches that are not visible when I open `*.dot` in Word as `*.dot` file.

My question is - what Word forms, tools I should use to see all the bookmarks and other invisible (possibly active) elements or placeholds in that exists in `*.dot` file and that can be used by some program that generates and fills `*.docx` files from `*.dot` files?

I can imagine and Bookmarks (special kind of placeholders) are the only elements. So - maybe I should seek some plugin that shows bookmarks and then copy those bookmarks from `report.doc` to `new_report.docx` and save it as `new_report.dot` and the the job will be done including the transfers of all the hidden riches from the old template file?

Comment: I disagree. It can be common practice to include *.dot file in the installation of some software piece and this software then can generate word documents on each separate installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you save this as a template, anything in the original .doc file will be in the template and will be in documents created from the template.

First, though, unless you are using Word 2003 or earlier, you would *save as .dotx*, not .dot. That is a macro-free template.

Here is my webpage on [Templates in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm). An earlier version of this is on the Microsoft website. I am giving this as a reference and to show that I know what I am talking about, not as the answer.

You can turn on viewing of bookmarks. This is in the Word options. You can also use Ctrl+G to bring up the GoTo dialog, pick bookmarks and display hidden bookmarks.

### There may be landmines as well as hidden riches.

You can and should use the **Document Inspector** under the File Tab (Windows). This can help you detect and remove hidden metadata that you may not want in your template.